# Is there a way to apply a bold weight to text before a set character, normal weight after it (or any type of css, really) without manual formatting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, formatting, pseudo-class

I'm working with an e-commerce client in a CMS environment (mybigcommerce.com) and the titles could use a lot of cleaning up to make them more readable, e.g.:

5/16" x 12" ExcelMate DrIll Bit and Panel Driver—used to install ExcelMate Drivers, etc.

I'm bringing over dozens, maybe hundreds, of products and wanted to see if there is a way to set up the product's h1 css to automatically format the fractions, and the text before and after the em dash—all without going in and manually adding a bunch of span tags. I know it's asking a lot for css alone, but is there a script that will do it?

The character that sets each set of style rules apart would be consistent—an em dash for one set, the fraction separator for the fraction styling—but the text before and after the separators is not, so :before and :after can't be easily utilized.

It's something I can do with print styles in InDesign which saves me tons of time, and it seems like it would come in very handy if there was a way to do it with jQuery and CSS—I know it would save me a ton of time on this project!

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

UPDATE: Sorry, I forgot to mention my second reason for wanting to do this dynamically: The client will take over regular updates once I'm done. The client is not a coder—it would be a challenge to have him apply an h1 tag with a class, or even a simple h1 tag alone, it would be incredibly difficult for him to apply spans within it. It would require a minimum of five spans to achieve this, so using .js or jQuery to apply the tags dynamically would not only save a lot of work, it would insure it gets done properly once I'm finished.

Comment: What is wrong with using tags (as long as you let jQuery generate them, of course) ?

Comment: Tags are fine, necessary, as long as they're applied dynamically and not manually—sorry if it wasn't clear that that is what I meant.

Comment: REVISED: Tags are fine—necessary—as long as they're applied dynamically and not manually. Sorry if it wasn't clear that that is what I meant. 

Having them be dynamically generated is exactly what I'm after... Do you know of a way to do that?! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This would not be possible alone with CSS.

CSS can be applied to a tag, or it's children.  The styles applied would apply to all the content of the tag.  If you need seperation, then you will need to modify the HTML to include some kind of tags on which you can apply the CSS.

You already have an idea on how to split this.  You do not have to do so manually, perhaps regular expression or other pattern matching to add tags.

Comment: Thanks Kami, yes some kind of pattern matching is going to be the best way, I suspect—just have to sort out how! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use a `:before{}` and `:after{}`  pseudo classes. But I don't think that fits your choices.

Another way might be to import a font library and use a javascript cufon to do this.  e-g you can filter the selections and have them use a different styles. e-g  headings and li will have a different font in below example.

It is just an example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Cufon.replace('h1, h2, h3, h4 , ul li', { fontFamily: 'Myriad Pro', textShadow: '#fff 1px 1px', hover:true,fontSize:'16px' });
</script>
```

Comment: I haven't tried using a Cufon yet... Not in any of my projects. I've read a little about them, but not tried. 

Wouldn't that still require tagging the various sections of the header? I initially thought about :before and :after, but it would require that the leading and trailing text be consistent, instead of the separator. Thanks!